# How to write a Ternary Operator for this operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to write a Ternary Operator below so the when `this.props.location.state.programId` is equal to `r.programschosen.map(e => e.id)` it outputs the name `r.programschosen.map(e => e.program_name)`. How to write it below?

```
    {
      id: "program",
      label: "Program",
      customCell: r => (
        <td>
          {this.props.location.state.programId}
          {r.programschosen.map(e => e.program_name).join(", ")}{" "}
        </td>
      )
    },
```

Comment: `this.props.location.state.programId` sounds like a string/number. `r.programschosen.map(e => e.id)` sounds like an array. How should they ever be equal?

Comment: I've edited you question to replace the "What's the best way" text with "How". No one's going to answer with the worst way to do that :). Stack Overflow has rules about opinion-based questions, and asking for the "best way" invites opinions over just methods for solving the issue. Please be sure to phrase your questions in a neutral, objective fashion in the future.

Comment: They are both numbers. this.props.location.state.programId = 28 and r.programschosen.map(e => e.id) = 5 & 28

Comment: I think what you want is when `r.programschosen.map(e => e.id)` includes `this.props.location.state.programId`, then show the name. Are we to assume you're using React for this, since you're using `props` and JSX?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am using JSX that's why I had to write it in that format. `this.props.location.state.programId` is from componentDidMount() function so when I go to a page it assigns an id which is `this.props.location.state.programId` but then I have an array that has a program_name + id in each index. What I want is if it sees that if it sees `this.props.location.state.programId` and id from `r.programschosen.map(e => e.id)` as equal then output the name related to that id :) Just not sure how to write it down

Comment: No need for a ternary, really. Just find the item in `programschosen` and if it's found, get the `program_name`. Something like `r.programschosen.find(e => e.id === this.props.location.state.programId)?.program_name`; the `?.` will return `null` if the item is not found.